# Perovskite's material parameters?

Tags: material-science

[Perovskite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perovskite)'s material parameters? What are the major material parameters being investigated? [For example, water solubility, absorption characteristics, surface energy etc]

Comment: Well, I shall modify the question then to approach this indirectly

Comment: Retracted. This may still be too broad but I have no idea since I don't know the field.

Comment: I am trying to find out what physical characteristics are most important, especially if a production environment is being investigated. Although Perovskites are used in a number of fields, their big well hyped potential is solar PV cells.

Comment: Investigated by whom? To determine relevant properties of a material you need to state the application. Besides, that isn't really a physics question.

Answer (score 1):

Perovskites is a huge family of compounds and different compounds have been explored for different properties.Some of the major parameters being surface adsorption,catalytic properties,effect of oxygen percentage on various properties. Perovskites are also widely studied with respect to their production environment as it can affect stoichiometry and thus can lead to dramatic changes in properties for some compounds.You can refer to books like "Properties of Perovskites" by K. Alex Mueller, "Properties and application of Perovskite type oxides" by LG Tejuca to get a better idea.